# prove that the following set is of the first category: $E = \{p \in C[0,1] : $ p is polynomial $\} $

Tags: calculus, general-topology

I need to prove that the following set is of the first category: 
$E = \{p \in C[0,1] :  $ p is polynomial $\} $

So, I thought to show the E is the union of the following sets:

$A_n = \{p \in C[0,1] :  $ p is polynomial of degree n $\}$ , in order to finish i need to prove that the interior of $\overline{A_n} $ is $\emptyset $.

Something else i thought of doing is taking $A_n = \{ f \in C[0,1] : f = a_n x \  ^ n \}$ .

but , im not sure how to prove that the interior of the closure of $A_n$ is empty.(in both cases)

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A_n = \{p \in C[0,1] :$ p is a polynomial of degree  $\le$ n }. Then $A_n$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $C[0,1]$, hence $A_n$ is closed and therfore

$\overline{A_n}=A_n$.

If we suppose that the interior of $A_n$ is not empty, then we get the contradiction $A_n=C[0,1]$.

This can be seen from:

Lemma: If $X $ is a normed space and $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ such that $Y$ contains an interior point, then $Y=X$.

Comment: A finite dimensional subspace of a normed space is closed.